# Do java objects get removed when a java application closes?

Tags: java, jvm

I've been learning about Java and how it uses garbage collection vs manual deallocation of objects. I couldn't find an answer to whether java objects get removed when a java application closes or not? What exactly happens in the JVM when, say, a small console application with an object

```
public class Hello {
    public String name = "Y_Y"; 
}
```

exists in memory and the console application is closed?

Thanks,
Y_Y

Comment: It might not be cleared, but the memory space is available for any other program to use and overwrite whatever address was holding that Java object.

Comment: When you say "it might not be cleared", does that means it is sometimes cleared? Does this happens when the heap is full or is it random?

Comment: By _cleared_, I mean if there was a value in that memory location, that value may not have been changed or set to 0. It would still have the value it had when the Java process was running.

Comment: It will be `free`d, in C lingo, which as @SotiriosDelimanolis correctly points out, does not always mean setting the memory to 0.

Comment: a TV without a remote Example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an application closes, the jvm stops running and all of its memory is returned to the host.

For all practical purposes, the heap and all object allocated there stop to exist.

If you're concerned about security, any process with raised privileges would be able to scan that memory and read whatever's left around.  It would have to do so before the memory gets allocated to another process.  But that could also happen while the original program/jvm is running.

Comment: Interesting., I could ask lots of questions about security but I'm satisfied with your answer. Kinda reminds me of hex editor programs. Thanks a lot for the fast response.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know for sure. The behavior is not specified or guaranteed. But you should not care too much about that. What you should care is that the memory is reclaimed.

If security is your issue, well it shouldn't be. Security cases should be treated when encountered. Rewriting the entire memory with 0 or garbage would make exit really slow.

What happens is the memory occupied by the string is freed on exit. 
If the object implements a finalize() method, it **may** be called.

Also, you can invoke the Garbage collector manually using `System.gc();`

The following is an extract from the Sun specifications.

> The specification for the Java platform makes very few promises about
>   how garbage collection actually works. Here is what the Java Virtual
>   Machine Specification (JVMS) has to say about memory management.
>
> The heap is created on virtual machine start-up. Heap storage for
>   objects is reclaimed by an automatic storage management system (known
>   as a garbage collector); objects are never explicitly deallocated. The
>   Java virtual machine assumes no particular type of automatic storage
>   management system, and the storage management technique may be chosen
>   according to the implementor's system requirements.1 While it can seem
>   confusing, the fact that the garbage collection model is not rigidly
>   defined is actually important and useful-a rigidly defined garbage
>   collection model might be impossible to implement on all platforms.
>   Similarly, it might preclude useful optimizations and hurt the
>   performance of the platform in the long term.
>
> Although there is no one place that contains a full definition of
>   required garbage collector behavior, much of the GC model is
>   implicitly specified through a number of sections in the Java Language
>   Specification and JVMS. While there are no guarantees about the exact
>   process followed, all compliant virtual machines share the basic
>   object lifecycle described in this chapter.